# How to remove 2 different values at the begining of character in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have table in Oracle SQL like below:

```
col1
------------
ABC|111
ABC|23
BBC|11112222
BBC|3123
```

Values in "col1" always start from BBC| or ABC| and values have different length.

As a result I need something like below, so I need to remove values BBC| or ABC| at the begining of each value in "col1":

```
col1
---------------
111
23
11112222
3123
```

How can I do that in Oracle SQL ?

Comment: If your question really somehow differs from your earlier question, then please state here.